# I am new to android development. Trying to create app with 3 activity. Error message: Exception raised during rendering

Tags: java, exception, null, point

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getDrawable(Resources_Delegate.java:189)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:845)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:687)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:454)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:144)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:406)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:283)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:105)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:95)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor841.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:259)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:285)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:122)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:930)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:950)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:309)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:501)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:328)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:396)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:209)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:608)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:734)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Other than that link, we can't really help you without any code.

Comment: Found the error and rectified it. Thanks for your kind support.